# Why doesn't my $q resolve and promise work like I think it does?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm always having problems with $q

Here is an example where the `.then` is fired right away

```
    function doit() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                template: '<p>this is modal</p><a ng-click="ok()">ok</a>',
                controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.ok = function () {
                        $modalInstance.close();
                    };
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                console.log('ok');
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed');
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Elsewhere:

```
    $scope.service.doit().then(
                $scope.variable = 5
            );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IngoVals/stqwanhm/

I got this in Fiddle when trying to model another similar setup where .then didn't fire at all. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the value `5` into `then` here:

```
$scope.service.doit().then(
    $scope.variable = 5
);
```

That code runs like this:

1. `$scope.variable` is assigned the value `5`
2. The result of the assignment expression (which is the assigned value, `5`) is passed into `then`

Both of those things happen *right away*, when you call `then`. They don't wait for the promise to be resolved.

You wanted to pass a *function* into `then` instead, and have the function set the variable:

```
$scope.service.doit().then(function() {
    $scope.variable = 5
});
```

Now you're passing in a function. The code *in* the function isn't run until it's called, which it will be later when the promise is resolved.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stqwanhm/1/)

The good news and bad news is that this is going to get a lot more concise as of ES6, because ES6 introduces "fat arrow" functions:

```
$scope.service.doit().then(() => $scope.variable = 5);
```

That also creates a function and passes it into `then` (on an ES6-enabled engine).

I say this is both good news and bad news because it's nice and concise (good!), and also very easy to miss when you're reading (bad!). :-)

Comment: Absolutely not the first time I make this error, but I have code, similar to this example I made but the .then part is never fi$red. I'm not sure how I could go about debugging.

I was trying to recreate that bug in jsFiddle but not succesfully. What is a good way to debug $q code?

Comment: @IngóVals: Just normal debugging (using the dev tools, setting breakpoints, etc.) is the only thing that comes to mind (unhelpfully :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fire right away, it's just you update scope property outside of then callback. This code:

```
$scope.service.doit().then(
    $scope.variable = 5
);
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
$scope.service.doit().then(function() {
    $scope.variable = 5
});
```

Anothe problem is so called [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns). Avoid creating redundant deferred object:

```
function doit() {
    return $modal.open({
        template: '<p>this is modal</p><a ng-click="ok()">ok</a>',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close();
            };
        }
    }).result.then(function () {
        console.log('ok');
    }, function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed');
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/stqwanhm/2/

Comment: Wow, I'm using this antipattern in several places. Will try this on my actual code problem tomorrow and see if I get a result.